# Is it normal for my derailleur cables to cross over on the down tube?

Tags: derailleur, shimano, cable, cable-routing

I've just picked myself up a Specialized Allez Sport 2014 road bike from Evans Cycles (UK).

I test rode the bike and I'm happy with the bike, but when I got home, and flipped the bike over to make a note of the serial number (for insurance) and I noticed that the derailleur cables cross over on the underside of the down tube.

[image: Down tube derailleur cable cross over]

The groupset on the bike is Shimano Sora, installed by the workshop at the Evans store, before I test rode it. Full specs can be found here: http://www.evanscycles.com/products/specialized/allez-sport-c2-2014-road-bike-ec052507

The is the first road bike I've owned with a Shimano groupset < 105 and I wanted to know if this is the normal way to route derailleur cables with Sora shifters?

I have owned a 105 groupset equipped bike in the past with externally routed cables and the cables weren't crossed over on that. My current race bike has internally routed cables, so I can't even check against that.

The potential issue I'm concerned about with the cables crossed over is that through rubbing against each other, they will wear more than they would normally. I'm also worried that the cables will be more likely to rub against the downtube, but I could just be being paranoid...

UPDATE: It looks like I'm not the only person to ask this question: http://forums.roadbikereview.com/components-wrenching/crossing-derailleur-cables-downtube-243700.html

It would seem (from the above discussion, at least) that this is not uncommon for Specialised bikes to cross over.

Still doesn't sit right with me though...

Comment: Nope, that's not normal, they should be parallel. It's a trivial problem to solve, though, just a case of rewiring the gear cables. If the bike is new, you have a good case for taking it back to the shop and asking them to do it - they'll have cables to hand and it'll only take someone half an hour. Unless maybe the shifters have been swapped around....but that would be strange and even then, the unshielded cables shouldn't cross.

Comment: Indeed, the bike is new as I mentioned in the question. It's annoying that I have to make another journey back there for such a trivial issue. Can you think of any reason why they would do this? I can't help thinking they did it for a reason...

Comment: Just to clarify...the left shifter is working the front derailleur, the right working the rear? I mean, that's convention. You sometimes get brakes swapped around ("British" vs "Continental" setup) but I haven't seen that with gears.

Comment: I think someone started mis-routing the cables and then continued cause they had started that way.

Comment: @PeteH Yes, that's correct. The gear levers are in the usual "British" layout - rear derailleur controlled by the right lever and the front derailleur controlled by the left.

Comment: Aren't integrated brake/gears always right-rear, left-front?

Comment: @MasterRoot24 if you do go back to the shop, please post something to tell us what they say.

Comment: My commencal meta (MTB bike) was like that as well.

Comment: @Emyr it is not always like that. In fact it depends on which side you drive on. If left, then right hand owns the front brake and if right, then opposite.

Comment: @Rilakkuma sorry, i meant the gears. I don't think (for example) Shimano makes any left-handed levers for controlling rear derailleurs

Comment: I think its how some bike manufactures cut corners to make building them easier or cheaper. I got a Giant Revel 29er from 2013 & the cables are routed allong the top tube & along the top of the upper rear stay. I used to have an old Trek & the cables were routed underneath the bottom bracket. After about a year or two of riding in the mountains the cables started to rust making my rear brake & shifter cables harder to operate. I honestly don't know what the F they were thinking but after switching to a Giant with the cables mounted on the upper tube I have been getting way more life out of the

Comment: @PeteH it's very normal. Or common.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is one of those questions that can start arguments between bike mechanics--to cross or not to cross the derailer cables. Crossing appears to be becoming more common on new bikes, if the cables aren't internal, but it's also going to depend upon the bike. Smoother shifting is reported by some from crossed cables. I would talk to the mechanic at your LBS about it. There could be manufacturer recommendations or anecdotal experience driving the decision.

Comment: Agreed. The more I look into this, the more it seems to be a conscious decision to do it that way. There also seems to be specific mentions of cables being crossed like this on Specialized bikes too.

Comment: +1, I stand corrected. I've not come across this before

Comment: Most of the major manufacturers ship bike to shops with the cabling already routed.  If your ride looks like this, check the rest of them in the shop, they probably all look like that because Specialized shipped them that way.

Comment: Note that routing this way keeps the cables more "inboard" and less likely to get hung up on something.

Comment: By what physical mechanism would crossing the cables make shifting smoother?

Comment: Was this done by a cross-eyed mechanic? There's no reason for doing this and because of friction it hampers smooth action of both derailleurs.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I'm by no means a sufficiently skilled mechanic, but I recall last year when I had my brake and derailer cables replaced. The two mechanics I was talking with, both of whom are extremely skilled and both are framebuilders on the side, had differing views on the subject. Both felt strongly, to cross or not to cross, but it was polite disagreement. I asked about crossing, and got the response, "That's a sure way to start an argument between mechanics." They gave me their differing views, and smoother shifting from crossing was acknowledged as true by the straight cable advocate.

Comment: I used to work for a Specialized dealership, this is a very common cable routing on road bikes.

Answer (score 11):

I have seen this frequently and routed my cables this way. By routing the shifter cable from the right side of the handlebar around the stem to the cable boss on the left side of the frame (and visa versa) I create a more gentle bend in the in the cable housing. A gentler bend creates less internal friction on the cable. Another benefit is less stress on the cable ends where they insert at the shifter body and frame boss.

Comment: Crossing used to be more common on smaller frames which had shorter lengths of housing from the shifter to frame stop than larger frames. One reason, this is seen more frequently on newer bikes is because cables on road bikes are now usually routed under bar tape. So all sizes have shorter lengths of free housing.  Before index shifting, the same type of housing was used for both brake and shift cables. Compression housing, aka SIS/index, now used for shift cables is stiffer than wound housing. And the plastic is also more brittle. Another reason you want less stress on the cable housing end.

Comment: There's a much simpler reason why it wasn't used on older derailleur bikes from before index shifting - they had downtube shifters, so there was no cable curve around the stem/headtube.

Answer (score 4):

This setup is used less for reduced friction (although many make this argument) and more to keep the cable housing off the head tube so that you don't damage the paint.  For example, running the right shifter cable to the right down tube  cable stop, this forces the cable housing to make a sharper bend forcing the cable housing to rub the head tube. If we run the right shifter to the left down tube cable stop, the bend is more gentle and the cable housing does not contact the head tube unless the handlebars are turned to extreme angles.